# DownloadFile works, DownloadFileAsync gets 0 bytes file

Tags: c#

I'm trying to download git from this url

```
https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.5-preview20150319/Git-1.9.5-preview20150319.exe
```

I did it using DownloadFile, it worked OK.

Now I try to do it with Async method, but it downloads 0 byte file. Here's the code:

```
public void downloadFile(string urlAddress, string location)
{
    using (var downloadClient = new WebClient())
    {
        downloadClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
        downloadClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);

        Uri URL = urlAddress.StartsWith("http://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? new Uri(urlAddress) : new Uri("http://" + urlAddress);
        _downloadStopWatch.Start();
        try
        {
            downloadClient.DownloadFileAsync(URL, location);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        _downloadStopWatch.Stop();

        while (downloadClient.IsBusy) { }
    }
}
```

where:

```
private string _location = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\test.exe";
```

And urlAddress is typed into textbox and passed textbox.text

I check the Completed handler and it says completed.

Why am I getting 0 byte file?

Comment: Funny, your code doesn't work with described URL as it uses the https scheme. And if I change it to http it works as expected...

Comment: Wow, I missed that. Corrected, it works now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The completed methods parameter AsyncCompletedEventArgs returns an error `The remote name could not be resolved: 'https'`.

In that case you should fall back to http

Depending on your target framework you could also use `await downloadClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(urlAddress, location);`

Comment: indeed, using await Is the way to go these days.